# V3 in-app billing - static testing, null purchase response

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am doing the static testing using the 'android.test. ...' purchase items.
'Purchased' seems to work OK.'Cancelled' and 'refunded' always produce a null purchase response when it gets to the listener. Is this what they are supposed to do? 
Other response information tracing back through the calls seems OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my knowledge:

android.test.cancelled and android.test.refunds both are called when if user has been cancel the purchase or subscription or if user has been refunded by the google wallet. so purchase was cancel for both the cases so that you will get response as a null.

**android.test.canceled**

> When you make an In-app Billing request with this product ID Google
>   Play responds as though the purchase was canceled. This can occur when
>   an error is encountered in the order process, such as an invalid
>   credit card, or when you cancel a user's order before it is charged.

**android.test.refunded**

> When you make an In-app Billing request with this product ID, Google
>   Play responds as though the purchase was refunded. Refunds cannot be
>   initiated through Google Play's in-app billing service. Refunds must
>   be initiated by you (the merchant). After you process a refund request
>   through your Google Wallet merchant account, a refund message is sent
>   to your application by Google Play. This occurs only when Google Play
>   gets notification from Google Wallet that a refund has been made. For
>   more information about refunds, see Handling IN_APP_NOTIFY messages
>   and In-app Billing Pricing.

check this [link](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static) for more information.

Hope it will help you.